# How can i make this an async function

Tags: javascript, node.js

When i run my below code i get the error that await is only supported in an async function. How can i make the below async as my route is async but i guess because i am calling a promise within my async function i need make that async to. Below is the route

```
contactRoutes.get('/:id', async(req, res) => {

    cb.getDoc(req.bucket, req.params.id ).then(result=>{

        var tasks = await cb.n1qlQuery_wId(req.bucket,req.N1qlQuery, cbQ.qContactTasks,req.params.id)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(tasks))

        res.json({ Success: true , Error: "", Message:"", Data: result.value})

       }).catch(err=>{
           res.json({ Success: false , Error: err, Message: ""})

       })


})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass a aync callback into your promise resolver `then` like this,

```
contactRoutes.get('/:id', async(req, res) => {

    cb.getDoc(req.bucket, req.params.id ).then(async (result)=>{
         ...........
    }

})
```

or you may also use `await` in your promise call like this,

```
contactRoutes.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  var result = await cb.getDoc(req.bucket, req.params.id)
  var tasks = await cb.n1qlQuery_wId(req.bucket, req.N1qlQuery, cbQ.qContactTasks, req.params.id)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(tasks))

  res.json({ Success: true, Error: "", Message: "", Data: result.value })
}).catch(err => {
  res.json({ Success: false, Error: err, Message: "" })
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
contactRoutes.get('/:id', async(req, res) => {
    try{
        let result = await cb.getDoc(req.bucket, req.params.id );
        let tasks = await cb.n1qlQuery_wId(req.bucket,req.N1qlQuery, cbQ.qContactTasks,req.params.id)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(tasks))
        res.json({ Success: true , Error: "", Message:"", Data: result.value})
    }
    catch(err){
        res.json({ Success: false , Error: err, Message: ""})
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the callback function in `.then` async. See code below.

```
contactRoutes.get('/:id', async(req, res) => {

cb.getDoc(req.bucket, req.params.id ).then(async result=>{

    var tasks = await cb.n1qlQuery_wId(req.bucket,req.N1qlQuery, cbQ.qContactTasks,req.params.id)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(tasks))

    res.json({ Success: true , Error: "", Message:"", Data: result.value})

   }).catch(err=>{
       res.json({ Success: false , Error: err, Message: ""})

   })


})
```

Answer (score 0):

you have add `async` to `then(...)`'s handler AND not the route. Why? Since, await is used in that handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
  contactRoutes.get('/:id', async(req, res) => {
    try {
      const result = await cb.getDoc(req.bucket, req.params.id )

      var tasks = await cb.n1qlQuery_wId(req.bucket,req.N1qlQuery, cbQ.qContactTasks,req.params.id)
      console.log(JSON.stringify(tasks))

      res.json({ Success: true , Error: "", Message:"", Data: result.value})

    } catch (err) {
        res.json({ Success: false , Error: err, Message: ""})
    }
  })
```